# iPhone - Passing touch event to MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is it possible to pass touch event (by coding) to MPMoviePlayerController?
I don't want to detect touch. Just pass touch event.
I want to generate an event and pass it to MPMoviePlayerController as if user touched the player. Something like user touched the player at location x=100 and y=100
(I can't give in depth details due to some restrictions).

Comment: You should really enhance your question with more details. What is it that you plan to accomplish? What do you mean by "I dont want to detect touch .... just pass touch event"? As it stands now, your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to place a transparent view over the movie player and handle touches for that view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending the MPMoviePlayerController and just making sure all the touch events are passed.

You can even do this reverse to make sure the player view is being touched by adding your player view as a subview and then overloading the touch events in your Controller. Then print out the touch and you can see if the player passed the touch from its view to you.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"Video Touched?? %@",touches); 
 }
```